# Verizon Samsung Galaxy S3...trying to change notification sound

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications

Phone has an annoying notification sound that I cannot get rid of.  Want to completely delete off my system if possible.  I've gone into settings under Sound and it has a different sound than the one that plays.  I have also changed to Apex Launcher and have no idea if that creates a problem.  I have gone into the Contacts and also changed the message alert but that hasn't made any difference. Can you please help before I lose my mind any further?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `Settings->Sound & Notifications->Notification Sound` and select `None` or whatever you like.
Samsung's settings application may have renamed some things but in theory that should do it.
If you don't like any notification sound **and** ring tone then you might want to set your ring tone volume to 0.